# How to edit HTML element of website by using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

This HTML code includes a button on a website:

```
<button ng-class="twoFactorAuthState()" ng-click="toggleTwoFactorAuth()" class="but-on-off on" data-functional-selector="game-settings-two-factor-auth">
    <span class="enabled">On</span>
    <span class="disabled">Off</span>
    <span class="cover"></span>
</button>
```

Is it possible to use JavaScript in the console window of Google Chrome to edit **but-on-off on** to **but-on-off off**, and include **disabled="disabled"** at the end of the first line? The result will look like this:

```
<button ng-class="twoFactorAuthState()" ng-click="toggleTwoFactorAuth()" class="but-on-off off" data-functional-selector="game-settings-two-factor-auth" disabled="disabled">
    <span class="enabled">On</span>
    <span class="disabled">Off</span>
    <span class="cover"></span>
</button>
```

I am able to make these changes with the Inspect Element option in Google Chrome, but I would like to achieve this programmatically. And I think it is worth to mention that this is not my website, so I cannot add any scripts to the source code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I know there are many talented people out there.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Introduction

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could try something like this in the console.

```js
var butOnOffElements = document.querySelectorAll('.but-on-off');

butOnOffElements.forEach(function(currentValue) {
  if (currentValue.classList.contains('on')) {
    //before replacing 'on' with 'off'
    console.log(currentValue.classList);

    //replace 'on' with 'off'
    currentValue.classList.remove('on');
    currentValue.classList.add('off');

    //after replacing 'on' with 'off'
    console.log(currentValue.classList);
  }
});
```

```html
<button ng-class="twoFactorAuthState()" ng-click="toggleTwoFactorAuth()" class="but-on-off on" data-functional-selector="game-settings-two-factor-auth">
    <span class="enabled">On</span>
    <span class="disabled">Off</span>
    <span class="cover"></span>
</button> <br/>
<button ng-class="twoFactorAuthState()" ng-click="toggleTwoFactorAuth()" class="but-on-off off" data-functional-selector="game-settings-two-factor-auth">
    <span class="enabled">On</span>
    <span class="disabled">Off</span>
    <span class="cover"></span>
</button>
```

Below is the documentation from MDN if you need to research how each this works:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: This worked like a sharm! The only problem is that it disables all other buttons as well. And I would like to turn the button off before disabling it, so to disable the functionality as well.

Comment: What does that do? How does it answer the question? Don't just blurt out code. Explain yourself! https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and help, @thomasP2balls! Are you able to explain how to change from "but-on-off on" to "but-on-off off" as well?

Comment: @thomasP2balls You are required to explain your code and not just blurt things out. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer This isn't reddit or some amateur board. You should know better by now.

Comment: I think I understand the code, @Rob, sir. butOnOffElements finds all the classes with "but-on-off", and for each found button, it disables it?

Comment: @Tovynato I've updated my answer so only if the button has called 'on' will it disable.

Comment: That worked fine, @thomasP2balls. But I am sorry to bother you more! How can I apply this for only one of the elements? Say for example the fifth element. How do I use "[5]"? And how can I set it to "but-on-off off" as well as disabling it? Now it only disables it. I want the switch on the button to change from on to off. Hope you understand!

Comment: Nevermind, @thomasP2balls! I managed to disable the one button with this code: "document.querySelector('button[ng-class="twoFactorAuthState()"]').disabled = true;". Now my remaining question is, how can I change "but-on-off on" to ""but-on-off off"?

Comment: I believe you can just use classList.remove() and classList.add(). Give me a minute ill update my answer.

Comment: It works perfectly well, @thomasP2balls! Thank you! The only problem is that when calling these, only the button is disabled, not the function. Do you know what to do with that?

Comment: Figured it out using this code, @thomasP2balls: "document.querySelector('button[ng-class="twoFactorAuthState()"]').click();"! Thank you so much for all your help!

Comment: Do you know how I can execute this JavaScript in the address bar of Microsoft Edge, @thomasP2balls? When doing so, the website closes and I see a "#". But it works fine on Google Chrome.